# How to find the input parameters of a web service dynamically?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am developing an android application which will have a screen with a list of web services. When user selects one of the web servcies, I need to take the input required by the web service from the user.

Is there any way to know the input parameters of the web service on the fly?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Do you have control over the web services?

Comment: I have the list of web services that are needed to be consumed. But the list could expand in future. That is the reason I want to make it dynamic and not hard code the input parameters for every web service.

Comment: Can you guarantee that they adhere to a particular format (for instance SOAP)?

Comment: Yes all services are SOAP based!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should require that your web services expose a [WSDL document](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) and rely on it.

Comment: Yes, but then is there any way get the input parameters from the wsdl document programatically?

Comment: It is an XML document so you either have to parse it or you should look for a library that does it

Comment: The WSDL is basically just an XML file, so yes you can parse this, as a WSDL file should comply to certain standards.